# Add/decrease value on click

Tags: javascript

I have some code that I've implemented as a counter, however, can this code be slightly modified to allow a button to increase a value by 200 and then decrease down to 0? I understand that ++x will increase, but I'm not sure why +x won't add? Is it something to do with strings?

**Javascript:**

```
let x = 200;
$('.counter-button.counter-up').on('click', () => {
  $('.counter-input.w-input').val( +x );
});

$('.counter-button.counter-down').on('click', () => {
  if (x > 0) {
    $('.counter-input.w-input').val( -x );
  }
});

$('.counter-input.w-input').change(function () {
  const num = Number($(this).val());
  // if it's a number
  if (num) {
    // assign its value to x
    x = num;
  }
});
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record (honoring your initial question): here's a '*vanilla*' solution.

```js
{
  document.addEventListener("click", addOrSubtract);
  
  function addOrSubtract(evt) {
    const from = evt.target;
    
    if (from.dataset.addvalue) {
      const numberInput = document.querySelector("input");
      const newValue = +numberInput.value + +from.dataset.addvalue;
      numberInput.value = newValue >= +numberInput.min 
        && newValue <= +numberInput.max ? newValue : numberInput.value;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="4000" value="0" readonly>
<button data-addvalue="200">increment</button> (max 4000)
<button data-addvalue="-200">decrement</button> (min 0)
```

Comment: Excellent! Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

.val() doesn't increase or decrease, it assigns. Try:

```
$('.counter-input.w-input').val( $('.counter-input.w-input').val() + x );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `+x` or `-x` it will just set that value as a value of the input. So you could first calculate the new value by adding or subtracting `x` of the current value based on the clicked button class.

```js
let x = 200;
let input = document.querySelector('.counter-input.w-input')
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.counter-button')

buttons.forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let value = +input.value;

    if (this.classList.contains('counter-up')) {
      value += x
    } else if (value > 0) {
      value -= x
    }

    input.value = value
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="counter-button counter-up">Up</button>
<button class="counter-button counter-down">Down</button>
<input value="0" type="text" class="counter-input w-input">
```

Comment: Great solution but needed javascript vanilla solution for this :)

Comment: @Dan Updated my answer with plain js solution. Also you've tagged your question with jquery.

Comment: You were right. Apologies, I'm new to StackOverflow. I've accepted the above answer as this resolved my issue. Your answer also solves but I'm unable to accept both answers.